# Magento 2 PWA Stripe REST API 3D Secure

Tags: magento, stripe-payments, progressive-web-apps

I'm running a Magento 2 integrated with a PWA, however, I'm not able to place an order with 3D Secure.

1. `stripe.createPaymentMethod({type: 'card', card: cardElement});`
2. POST to /rest/${storeCode}/V1/guest-carts/${cartId}/payment-information
3. I receive 400 with client secret
4. `stripe.handleCardAction(clientSecret);`
5. 3D Secure window pops up and I confirm
6. I make the same POST request from point 2
7. I receive 404 not found, but I would expect the response to be 200 and the order to be placed

Comment: Are $storeCode and $cardId set correctly in the 2nd request?

Comment: Yes, the variables are set correctly